# Switching themes using wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress plugin which allows user to enter name of four themes using four text boxes. Then based on some condition, at one point one theme out of the 4 gets activated.Then after some time based on some condition other theme gets activated.

if(condition_one)
{

Activate Theme1

}

else if(Condition_Two)

{

Activate Theme2

}

etc.

I tried using the below method.

```
    update_option('current_theme','ThemeName');
update_option('template','ThemeName');
update_option('stylesheet','ThemeName');
```

The themes are actually getting changed but is this the correct way to do it. Am i considering all the fields in the wp_options table. Is there a way using which by just passing the theme name all the relevant fields get updated.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to use the `switch_theme` function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme

Comment: @NikolyYordanov  i tried using switch_theme('twentyten','Twentyten');But when i activate the plugin i am getting this error.   Fatal error: Cannot redeclare twentyten_page_menu_args() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyten\functions.php:221) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentyten\functions.php on line 224